# Comparing two Statistics

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

Please consider the following problem and the solution to it. Is the solution
right?

Bob

Problem:

Test the hypothesis that the variances of yarn strength of the two yarns given
below are the same at $\alpha = 0.05$. I will call the first yarn A
and the second yarn B.
The sample mean for the strength of yarn A is $104$ with a sample standard deviation of $\sigma = 3.97$.
The sample mean for the strength of yarn B is $93$ with a sample standard deviation of $\sigma = 4.36$.
In both cases, there were $20$ samples taken.

Answer:

I setup the Null Hypothesis $H_0$ to be the the assumption that both variances
are the same. I also setup $H_1$ to be the assumption that both variances
are different.

We have $df=19$ for both samples.
\begin{eqnarray*}
\alpha &=& 0.05 \\
\frac{ \alpha }{2} &=& 0.025 \\
F &=& \frac{{\sigma_a}^2}{{\sigma_b}^2} = 1.206 \\
F_{19,19,0.025} &=& 2.51 \\
F_{19,19,0.975} &=& 0.398 \\
\end{eqnarray*}
Therefore, I conclude that there is no significant difference between the
two yarns.

Comment: Yes, this is correct.

Comment: Stef, thanks for the response. I would like to accept your answer so that you can get experience points but because you did it as a comment, I think I cannot do that.

Comment: If _population_ SD's are really 3.97 and 4.36 as you say, then there is nothing to test! They are _stated_ to be different. I suppose you intended these to be _sample_ SD's. In that case, please edit your question...and I suppose @Stef's Comment is correct.

Comment: @Bob Thanks Bob :)! Never mind it is ok like this!